# Storing custom class in a public VBA collection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm making a quiz generator application in Word with VBA. The user generates the questions one at a time, so I'm trying to store all questions in a public collection. The sub to add the question object to the collection is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Public questionCollection As VBA.Collection

'Initialize question collection
Sub addToQuestionCollection(cQuestion As Object)

    Dim key As Long
    'Set question collection if it has not yet been initialized
    If questionCollection Is Nothing Then
        Set questionCollection = New VBA.Collection
    End If

    'Generate key for question
    key = Bas04CRC32Hash.CRC32(cQuestion.question)

    'Assign key to question
    cQuestion.Id = key

    'Adds question object to question collection
    questionCollection.add cQuestion, CStr(key)

End Sub
```

The subroutine executes perfectly fine, but as soon as it's over the collection loses the value and become empty. I'm positive that questionCollection is never dimmed in my project (I must have checked 20 times by now) so the scope declaration can't be the issue. How can I ensure that the collection retains all of the question objects while the document remains open?

Thank you

Comment: Make sure the code is in a module and not in a userform.

Comment: The code is indeed in a public module

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging I found the answer:

My quiz generator uses OLEObjects to represent the questions. Apparently, creating an OLEObject dynamically resets global variables, which really sucks. If anyone knows a way around this I'd appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Can you use Forms controls instead? I imagine you've already thought of that.

Comment: Unfortunately they don't really suit my needs... I'm doing something very roundabout and probably ill-advised to deal with it:

I'm creating a password protected module that dynamically stores all the question data, and then when the quiz is evaluated it will build all of the classes at once. It definitely has it's drawbacks, but it seemed like the most feasible.

Comment: Just a thought: assuming you are actually adding objects to the document's surface, AIUI the problem arises because, when you do that, the Document Object's code is recompiled. So if the *code* is in a template that *isn't* the document where you are adding these controls, would it work? Could you represent the data you are storing in other ways (e.g. using Content Controls, if you are also displaying the data, or Custom XML Parts - both basically WIndows only - or Word Variables)?

Comment: Unfortunately the way the business wants this done is as one single program to make distribution easier. Word variables may be an option though, I hadn't considered that. I will investigate that and see if that provides a working solution.